TeXMaker compilation error
I am trying to compile a document (using TexMaker) that was initially setup by another person and I keep getting the following error:
Process started  This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2023) The top-level auxiliary file: SLO_book.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file SLO_book.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file SLO_book.aux (There were 2 error messages)
I am relatively new to LaTex so I know this is something I am overlooking and very easy to correct.

Are you sure the document uses bibtex at all?

Yes, it does use bibtex

Can you try to create a minimal document using bibtex and see if that works for you? If it throws the same (or similar) errors, can you please share it with us so we can take a look?

Analysing what goes wrong is kind of hard without seeing any actual code that produces the error, so to get the best help we can offer it'd be great if you could first help us help you.

the message means there are no \cite commands in your document so no bibliography to generate.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The two errors mean, that there is not \bibliographystlye{…} and not \bibliography{…} in the document. And as David already told, it seems, that there are also not \cite commands in the document. So for this document you should re-configure TeXmaker to not run BibTeX. Or alternatively you should only run PDFLaTeX (and then open the (internal) PDF Viewer).
